# Are Xamarin's Application.Properties preserved across app updates? If not, how?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, storekit

I'm storing state for an in-app purchase in Application.Properties (Xamarin). Every time I release an update, I find my app is reporting phantom purchases on iOS (via my analytics package).

My only good explanation for this behavior is that Application.Properties aren't being preserved. So the updated app thinks it is brand new, and when the user goes to "purchase" in the app, iOS allows them to restore the purchase, which is reported back to the app as a successful purchase.

Does Application.Properties persist across iOS app updates? If not, is there a way to do so? If it does, any other ideas for what is happening?

Comment: The documents is here:[persistence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/application-class#persistence). I think it should be there unless you uninstall it.

Comment: Thanks Jack. Problem is, I'm seeing lots of errors from users via AppCenter that show it isn't remembering the purchase state of the app, and I haven't been able to reproduce the problem locally.

Answer (score 0):

Properties are persisted as an xml file, so they should be preserved across app updates.